# Dynamic UITextView within Dynamic UITableViewCell height?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextview

I am just not finding a good solution to this issue. I have a UITextView subclassed in a UITableViewCell. Right now I have the TextView dynamically resizing, but the cell is not. That is because the heightForRowAtIndexPath is only being called on load. How can I have this called without calling cellForRowWithIndexPath (i.e. reloadData)...

Any help would be great! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually pretty simple, just use something like this inside the uitableviewcell

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,width,new height);
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Can't remember, but the superview of uitableviewcell should be the uitableview.

Comment: Doesnt seem to be updating the tableview. My current cell text is growing, and covering the next rows

Comment: Oh seems my TableView accidentally got disconnected from my outlet... works great, with some tweaking!